# COVID-19 SBA loan forigveness

Tags: united-states, taxes, loans, covid-19

The [COVID-19 Paycheck Protection Program](https://www.sba.gov/funding-programs/loans/coronavirus-relief-options/paycheck-protection-program-ppp#section-header-5) includes provisions for forgiving those loans.

Normally when debt is forgiven you have to [pay taxes on the forgiven debt](https://www.credit.com/blog/1099-c-in-the-mail-how-to-avoid-taxes-on-cancelled-debt-14927/).

Will recipients of Paycheck Protection Program loans need to pay taxes on those loans if they're forgiven?